# AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp' pip

Tags: python, websocket, pip

I am trying to use websocket.WebSocketApp, however it's coming up with the error: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'

I had a look at previous solutions for this, and tried to uninstall websocket, installed websocket-client and still comes up with the same error.

My File's name is MyWebSocket, so I don't think it has anything to do with that

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 10):

You've installed wrong websocket package. You installed [websocket](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket) but you need [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client). Uninstall both to cleanup the mess and reinstall `websocket-client`.

Comment: When I uninstall websocket, says "Cannot uninstall requirement websocket, not installed"

Comment: You have to verify what is in `site-packages/websocket/` directory. If there is `_app.py` with `WebSocketApp` then it's `websocket-client` and you should see why it's not imported. And ig there is no  `WebSocketApp` you should manually remove it and install `websocket-client`.

Comment: I just checked and there is no WebSocketApp, so I delete the websocket directory?

Comment: Yes, and install `websocket-client`.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just installing `websocket-client==1.2.0` is ok.

I encountered this problem when I was using `websocket-client==1.2.3`