# AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'

Tags: python, websocket

Relevant snippet of code:

pip install websocket-client

import websocket

def on_open(ws):
blahblah

def on_close(ws):
blahblahblah

def on_message(ws,message):
blahblahblah

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)

ws.run_forever()

I receive the error AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp' on j**upyter notebook** which is weird, because i was running the **exact same code** on **Google Colab** and I was not receiving any errors on there.

I tried everything!! I tried doing what was suggested here: [AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp' pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730108/attributeerror-module-websocket-has-no-attribute-websocketapp-pip)

I also tried this: [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141689/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-websocketapp)

I tried screwing around in my files and still no matter what I do I continue getting this error...

My python version is 3.8.3 btw. Does anyone have a clue as to what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try running from an open terminal or command prompt, I had the same problem trying to run code in ATOM with a python script package. I think has something to do with having multiple versions of Python installed.